# Division between columns returns a number with no decimals

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to divide two numerical values. In this example, z returns a number with one decimal place:

```
    x <- 10
    y <- 3
    z <- x/y

    z

    [1] 3.3
```

Without changing anything else in this example, R returns an integer, with no decimal places:

```
   x <- 2966634
   y <- 205.9
   z <- x/y

   z

   [1] 14408.
```

I want to get decimals placed and control that, but I could not find an answer.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error. When I run the code, it returns `[1] 14408.13` When you run `getOption("digits")` what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

You have `options(digits = )` let you fix the numbers of digits you want to show:

```
options(digits = 5)
x <- 2966634
y <- 205.9
z <- x/y

z
#[1] 14408

options(digits = 15)

z <- x/y
z
#14408.130160272
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but when I try to do that, dividing two columns into data.frame, I only get the number with no decimals...